# Properly inserting radiative heat flux into partial differential heat equation for a gas

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

The heat equation for a gas can be written as:

$$ \mu c_p \left( \boldsymbol{v} . \boldsymbol{\nabla} +  \partial_t \right) T = - \boldsymbol{\nabla} . \boldsymbol{j} + \partial_t P + S $$

with $\mu$ fluid mass density, $c_p$ calorific capacity, $P$ fluid pressure, $\boldsymbol{v}$ surronding fluid velocity field, $T$ temperature, $\boldsymbol{j}$ heat flux and $S$ a possible source term.

So I want to insert heat radiation into the heat flux $\boldsymbol{j}$, first we have:

$$ \boldsymbol{j} = \boldsymbol{j_{cond}} + \boldsymbol{j_{rad}} $$

with $\boldsymbol{j_{cond}} = - \lambda \boldsymbol{\nabla} T$, for the conduction flux (Fourier's law). This is a quantity in $W/m^2$, so it is a power density. The question is how to express properly $\boldsymbol{j_{rad}}$? I am interested by dissipative and large media (like atmosphere for instance), where the radiative heat flux can vary with position in space.

**What I propose**

We know that for a non scattering media (cloudless atmosphere for instance), the heat flux density per solid angle $I_{\omega}(\boldsymbol{r},\Omega,t)$ obeys to the Schwarzschild equation:

$$ \left( \boldsymbol{\Omega} . \boldsymbol{\nabla} + \frac{1}{c} \partial_t + \alpha \right) I_{\omega} = \alpha b_{\omega}(T) $$

with $\omega$ light frequency, $\Omega$ solid angle, $\alpha$ absorption coefficients (position, frequency dependents) $c$ speed of light, and $b_{\omega}$ Planck law. Once we find $I_{\omega}$ with the appropriate boundary condition, we have access to the heat flux density $K(\boldsymbol{r},\Omega,t)$ defined by:

$$ K(\boldsymbol{r},\Omega,t) = \int_0^{\infty} I_{\omega} d \omega . $$

Then I think now we can define the famous heat flux $\boldsymbol{j_{rad}}$ as:

$$ \boldsymbol{j_{rad}} (\boldsymbol{r},t) = \int_{\Omega} K(\boldsymbol{r},\Omega,t) d \boldsymbol{\Omega} $$

with $d \boldsymbol{\Omega}$ expressed (in spherical coordinates) as (not so sure):

$$ d \boldsymbol{\Omega} =  \sin \theta \ d \theta \ d \varphi \  \boldsymbol{e_r} .$$

Are you in agreement with that, or you know the specific formula to include the radiative heat flux?

Comment: You wrote: "...I am interested by dissipative and large media (like atmosphere for instance), where the radiative heat flux can very in fact..." What do you mean by "...where the radiative **heat flux can very in fact**..."  ? Do you mean "...can be very hot in fact..." ?

Comment: Thks Brendan I edit this, the Word is "vary". The heat flux can vary with position, because absorbed and reemited by gas. So its divergence is non zero. For instance this is the case of upcoming sun's rays in the atmosphere: the value is decreasing more and more as we approach earth surface.

Comment: In classical radiative transport theory $I_{\omega}$ would be called the specific intensity. Your relation between $j_{rad}$ as vector and specific intensity is missing a an angular component inside the integral - the specific intensity is a scalar, whereas the flux is a vector. For more detail, have a look into Mihalas&Mihalas - an introduction to radiation hydrodynamics.

Comment: Thks, OK I will take a look tomorow ;)! Note that my relation between $j$ and $I$ is vectorial since I use the vector solid angle, I see no problem at this level dont you? The vectorial aspect of the flux should be given by the vector solid angle, then with the intégral some directions vanish and others romain.